# Memory not release when calling c function in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios

I have developing an app that contain C-based core module and use cocoa touch to implement UI.
I will call c module to get data to show on screen but after that, the memory seems not be released. I use the profile tool to watch the leak, and there is no leak appear. But the Overall Bytes field of *All Allocations* would not reduce after release. That is, if I repeat the operation many times, the memory will increase every time and finally the app crash.

Here is the code I used.

```
In Interface ( ClassA.m file)

-(NSString*) getName:(int) index{
    int len = get_name_len(index);
    char* name = malloc(len); // name[len-1] indicate NULL CHAR
    get_name(name,index,len);
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name];
    free(name);
    name = nil;
    return result;
}

In UI (.m file)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;

...

-(void) update {
self.name = [ClassA getName:0];
}

...

-(void) dealloc{
self.name = nil;
[super dealloc];
}
```

I have about 100 data.
If I call self.name = [ClassA getName:0]. It will increase some memory and will not release after I call self.name = nil.
Then, if I call self.name = [ClassA getName:1]. It will increase again.
But if I call the same self.name = [ClassA getName:0] many times, it will only increase just one time. (Before call this function again, I will call self.name = nil first).

It's so strange.

I also try:

```
[ClassA getName:0];
self.name = [NSString* stringWithString@"ABC"];
```

And then, the memory will be correctly released.

I think this could indicate that the memory management of self.name and function:getName() should be fine.

What the problem it might be?

Comment: Heads up! You spelt retain incorrectly in your UI .m file.

Comment: Could you explain? what the problem is? I don't understand. Thanks

Comment: Consider dealloc self. [self dealloc]

Comment: Is it necessary to heap-allocate `name`? It seems like allocating on the stack could solve the leak.

Comment: Peter, what do you mean? Thanks!!

Comment: Should the Heap-allocation or stack not be the factor that cause the leak if I did correctly release the NSString ?

Answer (score 0):

Following up with regards to my comment... You have the following (in your UI .m file):

```
@property (nonatomic, reatin) NSString* name;
```

It should be:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
```

You spelt the keyword `retain` incorrectly.

Comment: Oh! Sorrty, it's a typo when I post. But in the code, I type the correct word "retain".

Comment: Shouldn't he be using copy instead of retain?

Comment: Well it depends... Copy will cause the ivar to be an actual copy of whatever is being assigned to it, whereas retain merely increases the retain count of the object, allowing for the ivar to point to the exact instance that it was assigned to.